# CentOS - Percona MySQL - Not Reading /etc/my.cnf

Tags: mysql, centos, selinux, audit, percona

I've compiled Percona 5.5 on my CentOS 6.1 server and it starts fine, however it doesn't appear to be reading my /etc/my.cnf file.

```
# In /etc/my.cnf
character_set_server = utf8
collation_server     = utf8_general_ci

mysql> show variables like 'character_set_server';
+----------------------+--------+
| Variable_name        | Value  |
+----------------------+--------+
| character_set_server | latin1 |
+----------------------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here, I expect to see a value of 'utf8', not latin1.

Currently the /etc/my.cnf set as a symbolic link pointed to a my.cnf file which is currently in version control, so it looks like:

```
root@host ~/MyFile/Setup # -> ls /etc/my.cnf
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 64 Dec 17 19:05 /etc/my.cnf -> /home/src/config/current/sys/etc/mysql/prod/confs-enabled/my.cnf
```

Upon some initial googling, it seems that I need to specifically set the path of the my.cnf file using the `--defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf`, flag. Which isn't currently being set through the CentOS daemon script:

```
ps auxfw > tmp.txt
vi tmp.txt
root     11798  0.0  0.1 106044  1488 pts/0    S    19:09   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/host.localdomain.pid
mysql    11875  0.1  4.3 499560 43936 pts/0    Sl   19:09   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --user=mysql --log-error=/var/lib/mysql/host.localdomain.err --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/host.localdomain.pid
```

So my question is, how do I add the ability to pass the `--defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf` flag to /etc/init.d/mysql daemon script?

Thanks.

-- **UPDATE** --

The problem appears to be because I have selinux policy set to enforcing, and trying to symlink my.cnf. Consider the following:

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 72 Feb  7 05:02 my.cnf -> /home/src/config/current/sys/etc/mysql/prod/confs-available/my-large.cnf
```

And the /home/src perms look like:

```
drwxrwxr-x. src  src  unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 config
```

If I copy the same exact file to /etc, it works, and if I disable selinux, it also works. So it has to do with the fact that mysql is trying to access /home/src.

Also, I did an audit2why, and it responded with:

```
Feb  8 17:32:20 app-mldrinks-aa-1 kernel: type=1400 audit(1328722340.203:17): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=2109 comm="mysqld" name="xvda" dev=devtmpfs ino=5801 scontext=unconfined_u:system_r:mysqld_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:fixed_disk_device_t:s0 tclass=blk_file

Was caused by:
    Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

    You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.
```

Is there a way to make this work without having to create a custom selinux module? I can't change the context type of `/home/src/config/current` to `mysqld_db_t` because everytime I push a config change a new directory will be created with `user_home_t`, which will contain the latest changes.

Comment: pastebin your /etc/default/mysqld file

Comment: and /etc/init.d/mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just copying the my.cnf from the version control path to /etc/my.cnf, and everything works fine. Going to go with this until I can drop more time and configure selinux to allow mysqld to access /home/src/config.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could get at it the other way - try to find which my.cnf is percona trying to read.

ie. `mysqld --help --verbose | head -n 30` and look for something like

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

Comment: Haven't forgot about this, had a dev server crash and cause me all number of setbacks. When I get back to investigating this issue I am going to try your solution.

Comment: your comment made me look at my answer again and I found a bug in it. it's fixed now :) good luck with your dev server :)

Comment: Looks like I'm having issues because I have a symlink for /etc/my.cnf, thinking it might be permission related. When I replaced symlink with actual file, it read it just fine.