# MySQL Not Reading Symlinks for Options Files my.cnf

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, debian, symlink, my.cnf

I'm running MySQL 5.5 on Ubuntu.

There is a my.cnf file in /etc/mysql/ where I would expect it to be. - Great!

For debian installations of mysql it is recommended that you do not edit the my.cnf file. There is an IncludeDir directive in the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file to look in the /etc/mysql/conf.d/ folder for more options files.

When I place this a file here:

```
/etc/mysql/conf.d/my-local.cnf
```

MySQL reads the file and overrides anything in /etc/mysql/my.cnf.

Great! :-)

**Here's the problem:**

I keep my local copy of the /etc/mysql/conf.d/my-local.cnf file in source control and want to update it periodically for the whole team. So, my solution is to symlink it:

```
cd /etc/mysql/conf.d/
ln -s /path/to/my/my-local.cnf my-local.cnf
```

MySQL does not read this symlink.

I have verified the following:

- Both the physical file and the symlink have the .cnf file extension as per mysql's manual.
- The mysql user has access to this file
- Every user has access to this file
- The mysql user has access to the symlink
- Every user has access to the symlink

So to summarise, MySQL will read and parse when there is a physical file in the /etc/mysql/conf.d/ folder. Mysql will not read a symlink in this folder.

Any ideas anyone? Could this be a debian/ubuntu issue?

A similar, but unresolved and slightly different problem was outlined [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/341958/centos-percona-mysql-not-reading-etc-my-cnf).

Comment: is apparmor active?

Comment: @Thomas Berger

OK, so [Apparmor](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/Main_Page) is active. The only way around this was to disable Apparmor for MySQL, like so:

`sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld /etc/apparmor.d/disable/usr.sbin.mysqld`
`sudo service apparmor restart`

This is a development machine, so this solution is fine. However, if I wanted to distribute config files across servers like this in a live environment I wouldn't be happy with this solution.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Apparmor does not know anything about the new location of the `my.cnf`

The MySQL Server follows the symlink and tries to open the destination. But apparmor denies this.

To fix the problem, you have to add the path to the `my.cnf` to `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`

Comment: Potentially the file could be anywhere on a user's development machine. That's the reason I'm using a symlink. I tied to add the location of the symlink as follows: `/etc/mysql/conf.d/symlinked-file.cnf` directly underneath the `/etc/mysql/conf.d/*` line however, this did not work.

Answer (score 2):

It may be caused by apparmor which is enabled for mysqld by default from ubuntu 9.0.4. Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppArmor .

- You can modify site-specific additions in /etc/apparmor.d/local/. I've suffered the same problem and edited /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld to make it work. Be aware of the last comma in the policy file.

  ```
  # Site-specific additions and overrides for usr.sbin.mysqld.
  # For more details, please see /etc/apparmor.d/local/README.

  # vim:syntax=apparmor

  /etc/mysql/conf.d/* rl,
  @{HOMEDIRS}/** rwk,
  ```
- After editing /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld, restart apparmor service by `service apparmor restart`. There should be no error or warning about /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld .
- In my case, I wanted to use datadir and site-specific my.cnf located in users's home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities come to mind:

- Create the symlink in the other direction, i.e.

  ```
  /home/developer/my-local.cnf -> /etc/mysql/conf.d/my-local.cnf
  ```
- Use a hard link instead.
- Put `/etc` under version control using a tool such as etckeeper.